# Display result in readonly text box

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and java. I am trying to get the output result of number of words into a readonly text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>input details </p>

<textarea id="input"></textarea>  

<div>
<br>
<button onclick="myfunction()">submit</button> 
        <br>
        <p>result </p>
      
      <input type="text" name="input" size="2" readonly>
        </div>
        
<script>  
        function myfunction() { 
        
        var name = document.getElementById("input").value;
        
      var val = document.getElementById("input").value;  
            if (val != "") {  
                words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length; 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried playing around with the code, but can't get any result into the text field.

Comment: `name="input"` vs. `document.getElementById("input")`. You should have `id="input"` instead. While technically there is `getElementsByName()`, that gives you a collection (note the plural). `name` is not expected to be unique, while `id` is.

Comment: It is not Java, it's Javascript. Do not confuse them, they are totally different languages.

Comment: i have tried changing it to '<input type="text" id="input" size="2" readonly>' but it does not work

Comment: Your code as shown above, contains syntax errors. Have you not at least checked the browser console for errors, before you came asking here?

Comment: And if you are trying to get a value _into_ a field, then there should be a `[something].value = ...` assignment somewhere, but I am not seeing any.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to HTML and JavaScript - it can be a bit frustrating sometimes though.

I can see a couple of reasons why this might not be working:

1. You are using `getElementById`, but have not assigned an `id` to your inputs
2. You have some mismatched curly braces (`{`) - if you open one, you need to close it
3. You are not actually doing anything with the result of your calculation
4. You have called both your input and the output field `input`, which will lead to confusion. Give them both different values for `id`.

To help make finding issues easier, I would recommend trying to keep your code nicely indented and use a good IDE (vscode from Microsoft is free, but there are others).

This should work for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>input details </p>

<textarea id="input"></textarea>

<div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">submit</button>
    <br>
    <p>result </p>

    <input type="text" id="output" size="2" readonly>
</div>

<script>
    function myfunction() {
        var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if (val != "") {
            words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;
            document.getElementById('output').value = words;
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```